# rpmbuild adding extra perl dependencis in oracle 11g client rpm

Tags: linux

I have installed Oracle 11g 32-bit full client on RHEL 6.3. I created its RPM. I then tried to install the RPM in another server but it shows various dependencies of Perl:

```
Error: Package: Oracle32bitFullClient-11.2-2.i386 (/Oracle32bitFullClient-11.2-2.i386)
           Requires: perl(RPC::PlServer)
```

I tried with Autoprov : 0, Autoprov :1 and without Autoprov line in spec, but it still requires many packages.

How can I get rid of this so that the RPM can be installed with all the required packages?